# Hide Master View on iPad landscape mode UISplitViewController iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a FlyoutNavigation component which derives from UISplitViewController, So when I show it in ipad portrait mode, the master view hides by default and I can toggle it properly, but when I change the orientation to landscape the Masterview shows all the time and I cannot even Toggle it.

Is there a way I can hide/unhide it?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting

`splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden`

Comment: I get the splitViewController as null if I try this

Comment: You need to assign it as per your implementation like -


UISplitViewController *splitViewController = your split View Controller and then try above code

Comment: Yes I did the same. But I got *splitViewController as null

Answer (score 1):

Try in appDelegate like this :

```
guard let splitViewController = window?.rootViewController as? UISplitViewController  
else { fatalError() }

splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = .primaryHidden
```

Comment: can you format code properly. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks